# Excel VBA - cannot .find date string in range

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote some VBA script to search a range of dates in a list, it can find the dates, but for some reason it cannot match them to the target range.  I tested the target range with a vlookup which does return a match, but the .find code doesn't seem to work in the same way.

For example, The sourcecolumnvalue will pick up a date in its range (say 01/02/2015).  The sourcecolumnvalue will reflect this but cannot seem to find this in the target range  as set within the .find string.

Am I doing something wrong with this code?

```
Sub Finddates()
Dim SourceColumnValue As String, sourcerow As String, targetrow As String
Dim M As Long, O As Long, TargetValue As Long, actualsourcerow As Long, actualtargetrow As Long, actualtargetcolumn As Long, sourcedateposition As Long
TargetValue = dumpsheet.Cells(rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
sourcedateposition = dumpsheet.Cells(rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).row

'Loop Source Column
For F = 1 To sourcedateposition
SourceColumnValue = dumpsheet.Cells(F, 5).Value


   'Get Target Column Match to Source
   Set TargetColumnRange = dumpsheet.Range("G2:G" & TargetValue).Find(What:=SourceColumnValue, _
                                                           LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                                           LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                                           SearchOrder:=xlByRows)
               'if a match is found
               If Not TargetColumnRange Is Nothing Then
                  TargetColumnRange.Value = SourceColumnValue

                       For O = 1 To dumpsheet.Range("A2:A" & rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
                         Sourcename = ActiveCell(O, 1).Value
                         sourcerow = ActiveCell(O, 2).Value
                         targetrow = ActiveCell(O, 3).Value

                         actualsourcerow = CInt(sourcerow)
                         actualtargetrow = CInt(targetrow)
                         actualtargetcolumn = CInt(TargetColumn)

                         CapexTargetSheet.Activate
                         Cells(actualtargetrow, actualtargetcolumn).Value = CapexSourceSheet.Cells(actualsourcerow, F).Value
                    Next O
               End If
Next F
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you able to post a sample file for us to work with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to write some code using a loop rather than using the .find which happened to be very inconsistent with dates.  I read in another article that using strings for dates is better because the actual numerical value of the date gets stored in the string.   I converted the source and target dates to strings and then did a match using a loop which works well.  But thank you for your answer, it did put me on the right track!

See below

```
Dim SourceColumnValue As String, sourcerow As String, targetrow As String, targetcolumnvalue As String, sourcecolumnnumber As String
Dim M As Long, O As Long, P As Long, TargetValue As Long, actualsourcerow As Long, actualtargetrow As Long, actualtargetcolumn As Long, sourcedateposition As Long, actualsourcecolumn As Long, targetdateposition As Long
Dim Copysource As Range, pastetarget As Range

TargetValue = dumpsheet.Cells(rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
sourcedateposition = dumpsheet.Cells(rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).row
targetdateposition = dumpsheet.Cells(rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).row

'Loop Source Column
For F = 1 To sourcedateposition
SourceColumnValue = dumpsheet.Cells(F, 5).Value
       'Get Target Column Match to Source

                ' Loop to compare strings
                    For P = 1 To targetdateposition
                    targetcolumnvalue = dumpsheet.Cells(P, 7).Value
                    If targetcolumnvalue = SourceColumnValue Then

                       TargetColumnRange.Value = SourceColumnValue
                       targetcolumnvalue = dumpsheet.Cells(P, 8).Value
                       sourcecolumnnumber = dumpsheet.Cells(F, 6).Value

                       For O = 1 To dumpsheet.Cells(rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp).row
                           If O > 1 Then
                           Sourcename = dumpsheet.Cells(O, 1).Value
                           sourcerow = dumpsheet.Cells(O, 2).Value
                           targetrow = dumpsheet.Cells(O, 3).Value

                           'Set Integers
                           actualsourcerow = CInt(sourcerow)
                           actualtargetrow = CInt(targetrow)
                           actualtargetcolumn = CInt(targetcolumnvalue)
                           actualsourcecolumn = CInt(sourcecolumnnumber)


                           'Copy and Paste
                           Set Copysource = SourceSheet.Cells(actualsourcerow, actualsourcecolumn)
                           Set pastetarget = TargetSheet.Cells(actualtargetrow, actualtargetcolumn)
                           Copysource.Copy
                           pastetarget.PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
                          End If
                      Next O
                   End If
                Next P
Next F
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `FIND` with dates is finnicky, see [here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DateTimeVBA.htm#Finding)

Your code worked on my tested when I changed

```
Set TargetColumnRange = dumpsheet.Range("G2:G" & TargetValue).Find(what:=SourceColumnValue, _
                                                           LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                                                           LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                                           SearchOrder:=xlByRows)
```

to

```
Set TargetColumnRange = dumpsheet.Range("G2:G" & TargetValue).Find(what:=DATEVALUE(SourceColumnValue), _
                                                           LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                                                           LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                                           SearchOrder:=xlByRows)
```

Comment: Nope - just experienced :)  Thanks for the quick close-out.

Comment: It does behave funny, I ran it for the second time and it skipped over the dates, the first time it worked.  I have reset excel and restarted and will try again