# Excel VBA - .find not consistent when working with dates

Tags: vba, excel

I posted a question yesterday around using .find with a date, unfortunately my problem still exists.  My issue is that using .find using a date as a string returns a nothing value with some source spreadsheets, yet it works with others.  Code is below, is there any method to getting consistent results using .find using dates?

**Update**: I have posted more code below to show the total section of code and what it does.  The date find section is shown in the second sectoin of code, the first section takes data from teh source and target spreadsheets, consolidates them and then finds matches in the source and target sheets.  The matches are both peoples names, and date of posting, once it finds a match for both, the names are returned as a row number, and the date of posting is returned as a column number.  It uses these references to copy/paste cell values located in the source and target row/column references.

```
Sub MapValues(SourceSheet As Worksheet, TargetSheet As Worksheet, dumpsheet As Worksheet)
Dim Sourcename As String, 
namefind As Range, TargetColumnRange As Range
Dim Sourcelrow As Long, targetlrow As Long,
Dim I As Long, lngCnt As Long
Dim DateStore As Variant
Dim c As Range, D As Range

GoTo Capex
Capex:

'Declare the ranges with Names
SourceSheet.Activate
Sourcelrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
TargetSheet.Activate
targetlrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).row

'redimension the name storage array



'loop through the source sheet names
SourceSheet.Activate
lngCnt = 2
For I = Sourcelrow To 1 Step -1
    Sourcename = SourceSheet.Range("A" & I).Value


        'find matches in the target sheet
           TargetSheet.Activate
            Set namefind = ActiveSheet.Range("E528:E" & targetlrow).Find(What:=Sourcename, _
                                                               LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                                               LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                                               SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                                               SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                                               MatchCase:=False, _
                                                               SearchFormat:=False)
                   'if a match is found
                   If Not namefind Is Nothing Then
                   dumpsheet.Range("A" & lngCnt).Value = namefind.Value
                   dumpsheet.Range("B" & lngCnt).Value = SourceSheet.Range("A" & I).row
                   dumpsheet.Range("C" & lngCnt).Value = namefind.row
                   lngCnt = lngCnt + 1
                   End If
Next I

Dim namerow As Long, actualrow As Long, actualcolumnsource As Long, actualcolumntarget As Long, daterow As Long
Dim actualcost As Range
Dim actualcostvalue As String, targetcolumn As String
Dim F As Long, G As Long, H As Long


dumpsheet.Activate
namerow = dumpsheet.Cells(rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
actualcolumnsource = SourceSheet.Cells(5, Columns.Count).End(xlToRight).row
actualcolumntarget = 44

lngCnt = 0
TargetSheet.Activate

'Create the Column Matches
ReDim DateStore(0 To actualcolumnsource)
For lngCnt = LBound(DateStore, 1) To UBound(DateStore, 1)
   If lngCnt = 0 Then
    DateStore(lngCnt) = SourceSheet.Cells(5, lngCnt + 1).Value
   Else
    DateStore(lngCnt) = SourceSheet.Cells(5, lngCnt).Value
   End If
Next lngCnt
dumpsheet.Range("E2").Resize((UBound(DateStore) - LBound(DateStore)) + 1, 1).Value = _
                                  Application.Transpose(DateStore)
lngCnt = 0
Erase DateStore

ReDim DateStore(0 To actualcolumnsource)
For lngCnt = LBound(DateStore, 1) To UBound(DateStore, 1)
   If lngCnt = 0 Then
    DateStore(lngCnt) = SourceSheet.Cells(5, lngCnt + 1).Column
   Else
    DateStore(lngCnt) = SourceSheet.Cells(5, lngCnt).Column
   End If
Next lngCnt
dumpsheet.Range("F2").Resize((UBound(DateStore) - LBound(DateStore)) + 1, 1).Value = _
                                  Application.Transpose(DateStore)

ReDim DateStore(0 To actualcolumntarget)
For lngCnt = LBound(DateStore, 1) To UBound(DateStore, 1)
   If lngCnt = 0 Then
    DateStore(lngCnt) = TargetSheet.Cells(5, lngCnt + 1).Value
   Else
    DateStore(lngCnt) = TargetSheet.Cells(5, lngCnt).Value
   End If
Next lngCnt
dumpsheet.Range("G2").Resize((UBound(DateStore) - LBound(DateStore)) + 1, 1).Value = _
                                  Application.Transpose(DateStore)


lngCnt = 0
Erase DateStore


ReDim DateStore(0 To actualcolumntarget)
For lngCnt = LBound(DateStore, 1) To UBound(DateStore, 1)
   If lngCnt = 0 Then
    DateStore(lngCnt) = TargetSheet.Cells(5, lngCnt + 1).Column
   Else
    DateStore(lngCnt) = TargetSheet.Cells(5, lngCnt).Column
   End If
Next lngCnt
dumpsheet.Range("H2").Resize((UBound(DateStore) - LBound(DateStore)) + 1, 1).Value = _
                                  Application.Transpose(DateStore)

lngCnt = 0
Erase DateStore


'Format the date ranges as dates before date match commences.


On Error Resume Next
For Each c In dumpsheet.UsedRange.Columns("G").Cells
    If Not IsEmpty(c) Then
    c.Value = CDate(c.Value)
    c.NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
    End If
Next c


For Each D In dumpsheet.UsedRange.Columns("E").Cells
   If Not IsEmpty(D) Then
   D.Value = CDate(D.Value)
   D.NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
   End If
Next D
```

**Section 2:**

```
Dim SourceColumnValue As String, sourcerow As String, targetrow As String, targetcolumnvalue As String, sourcecolumnnumber As String
Dim M As Long, O As Long, TargetValue As Long, actualsourcerow As Long, actualtargetrow As Long, actualtargetcolumn As Long, sourcedateposition As Long, actualsourcecolumn As Long
Dim Copysource As Range, pastetarget As Range

TargetValue = dumpsheet.Cells(rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
sourcedateposition = dumpsheet.Cells(rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).row
'Loop Source Column
For F = 1 To sourcedateposition
SourceColumnValue = dumpsheet.Cells(F, 5).Value
       'Get Target Column Match to Source
       Set TargetColumnRange = dumpsheet.Range("G2:G" & TargetValue).Find(What:=DateValue(SourceColumnValue), _
                                                               LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                                                               LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                                               SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                                               SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                                               MatchCase:=False, _
                                                               SearchFormat:=False)

                   'if a match is found
                   If Not TargetColumnRange Is Nothing Then
                       TargetColumnRange.Value = SourceColumnValue
                       targetcolumnvalue = dumpsheet.Cells(TargetColumnRange.row, 8).Value
                       sourcecolumnnumber = dumpsheet.Cells(F, 6).Value
                       For O = 1 To dumpsheet.Cells(rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp).row
                           If O > 1 Then
                           Sourcename = dumpsheet.Cells(O, 1).Value
                           sourcerow = dumpsheet.Cells(O, 2).Value
                           targetrow = dumpsheet.Cells(O, 3).Value

                           actualsourcerow = CInt(sourcerow)
                           actualtargetrow = CInt(targetrow)
                           actualtargetcolumn = CInt(targetcolumnvalue)
                           actualsourcecolumn = CInt(sourcecolumnnumber)

                           Set Copysource = SourceSheet.Cells(actualsourcerow, actualsourcecolumn)
                           Set pastetarget = TargetSheet.Cells(actualtargetrow, actualtargetcolumn)
                           Copysource.Copy
                           pastetarget.PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
                          End If
                      Next O
                   End If

Next F





CleanUp:

'Set Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29203887/excel-vba-cannot-find-date-string-in-range

Comment: Suggest you post an example of exactly what you are doing in your prior question (exact format of date being seached for, and search date range)

Comment: That might be the answer i'm looking for, the dates being displayed are in Australian format, but Excel is reading them from an American format, I could try converting them back to their actual values and search for that rather than the displayed dates.

Comment: Check the updated code, see if anything in there points to an issue.

Comment: This is not a duplicate, as far as I can tell. OP is saying that proceeding with an answer to a prior question has lead to a further question.